# what happens while taking correlation for correlation matrix

Tags: correlation

What does the correlation matrix of correlation matrix represent? Is it second order correlation?

```
x = cor(z)
y = cor(x)
```

Does y second order correlation of z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [stochastic volatility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_volatility) models, which are popular in finance and energy risk.

In these models the volatility (variance) itself is the random variable, just like others. As such it has all the properties: covariance, autocorrelations etc.